# Find an existing COM-Addin (excel) and update it

Tags: comaddin

I get all existing COM-Addins in Excel by using " Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.COMAddIns".

In my case, I have 8 COM-AddIns. 2 of them (A and B) are from my solutions and they are displayed in two different custom Ribbons with the same name. As I have mentioned, they are coming from different solutions.

I'm using Ribbon.designer and I would need to customize these 2 Ribbon in order to have only ONE Ribbon with Groups and Buttons from both (I don't want to use TabAddIns Office Built-In).

I am not able to access to Ribbon A (and customize it) if I'm running the solution of Ribbon B and vice-versa.
Do any of you guys know if that's possible?

See the image in order to understand better. 
It has been done once Excel is open and I want to do it at run-time:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sba5pskuzh6hbe9/Image.jpg

Many thanks in advance